# Number of ways of adding m non-negative integers to get the sum of n

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have $x + y = 10$ what is the number of solutions for non-negative integers?

$$
0 + 10 = 10 \\
1 + 9 = 10 \\
2 + 8 = 10 \\
3 + 7 = 10 \\
4 + 6 = 10 \\
5 + 5 = 10 \\
6 + 4 = 10 \\
7 + 3 = 10 \\
8 + 2 = 10 \\
9 + 1 = 10 \\
10 + 0 = 10 
$$

we have 11 solutions.

Now Suppose we have $x + y + z = 10$ what is the number of solutions for non-negative integers?

$$
0 + (x+y = 10) = 10 \ (11 \text{ ways}) \\
1 + (x+y = 9) = 10 \ (10 \text{ ways})\\
2 + (x+y = 8) = 10 \ (9 \text{ ways})\\
3 + (x+y = 7) = 10 \ (8 \text{ ways})\\
4 + (x+y = 6) = 10 \ (7 \text{ ways})\\
5 + (x+y = 5) = 10 \ (6 \text{ ways})\\
6 + (x+y = 4) = 10 \ (5 \text{ ways})\\
7 + (x+y = 3) = 10 \ (4 \text{ ways})\\
8 + (x+y = 2) = 10 \ (3 \text{ ways})\\
9 + (x+y = 1) = 10 \ (2 \text{ ways})\\
10 + (x+y = 0) = 10 \ (1 \text{ ways})
$$

we have $11 + 10 + \dots + 1 = \frac{(10 + 1)\times(10 + 2)}{2} = 66$ solutions.

Now Suppose we have $a + x + y + z = 10$ what is the number of solutions for non-negative integers?

$$
0 + (x+y+z = 10) = 10 \ (66 \text{ ways}) \\
1 + (x+y+z = 9) = 10 \ (55 \text{ ways})\\
2 + (x+y+z = 8) = 10 \ (45 \text{ ways})\\
3 + (x+y+z = 7) = 10 \ (35 \text{ ways})\\
4 + (x+y+z = 6) = 10 \ (28 \text{ ways})\\
5 + (x+y+z = 5) = 10 \ (21 \text{ ways})\\
6 + (x+y+z = 4) = 10 \ (15 \text{ ways})\\
7 + (x+y+z = 3) = 10 \ (10 \text{ ways})\\
8 + (x+y+z = 2) = 10 \ (6 \text{ ways})\\
9 + (x+y+z = 1) = 10 \ (3 \text{ ways})\\
10 + (x+y+z = 0) = 10 \ (1 \text{ ways})
$$

we have $11 + 10 + \dots + 1 = \frac{(10 + 1)\times(10 + 2)\times(10 + 3)}{6} = 286$ solutions.

So I think the generalized solution for having sum $n$ given $m$ variables is $\frac{\frac{(n+m-1)!}{n!}}{(m-1)!}$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: If you follow the link in the previous comment, you should discover that you are on the right track. Nice work!